# Change the contents of a html element when a menu item is clicked

Tags: php, html

I would like to load the contents of different HTML files into an element in my index.html file when different links in the menus are clicked. Essentially allowing me not to include the menus in many different HTML files making maintenance much easier.

Specifically, I want to change the contents of the  element in the HTML below, showing different links to equipment manuals/blueprints/etc based on the department selected from the top dropdown menu or the side menu.This HTML(to be inserted into ...) would come from a separate file for each "page" menu option.

I have seen that there are similar questions with answers, but I am having a hard time getting my head around their solutions and I am hoping someone can explain what to do within the context of my own code.

I asked a similar question yesterday, but it was confusing even to me when I read it again this morning, so I'm trying again with what is hopefully clearer language.

I'm not set on a particular method though I was leaning towards PHP because I think doing it server side would be easier on some of the old android-zebra scanners we use here that no longer receive browser updates. And as the site will not be accessed often or by many people at once there is no need to distribute the workload to the clients. But again, if there is a better way I'm not attached to PHP. JS or anything that works is good enough for me.

This feels like it should be super simple since many websites look like they must do what I'm trying to get at.

Any suggestions anyone can provide would be most appreciated!

Here Is the HTML for my site as it stands:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="intranet">
        <meta name="author" content="Eric ----, eric@----.com">

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/hd_style.css" media="screen">

    </head>

    
      <body>

        <!-- center the whole page in the browser -->
        <div class="center">

          <!-- dropdown top menu --> 

          <nav id="wrap">
            <ul class="navbar">
              <li>
                <a href="#"> Shipping </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"> Fabrication </a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"> Weld </a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"> Paint </a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"> Assembly </a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"> Office </a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Place Holder </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>        
            </ul>
          </nav> 

          <div class="container">
              <!-- left side menu -->
              <aside class="sidenav">

                <img id="hdlogo" src="images/HD.jpg" alt="logo failed to load" >

                <nav id="sidebar"> 
                  <a href="#">Directory</a>
                  <a href="#">Parts</a>
                  <a href="#">PTO</a>
                  <a href="#">Calandar</a>
                  <a href="#">More</a>
                  <a href="#">Buttons</a>
                  <a href="#">Here</a>  
                </nav>

              </aside>
              <main>
                          <!-- Diffrent content goes here based on menu selection-->

                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi. Dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra. Nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla. Integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus. Eros donec ac odio tempor. Est sit amet facilisis magna. Eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut. Vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo.

              </main>

          </div>
    
          <div class="vl"></div> <!-- produces a vertical line at the right of the page for aesthetic purposes--> 
          
        </div>
        
      </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: The biggest challenge of answering this is not so much coming up with a solution, as choosing from the dozens, maybe hundreds, of different technologies that could be used to achieve this. It's kind of like asking a forum of artists how to draw a human figure - do we teach you sketching, watercolour, or oil painting? Will you be more interested in realism, impressionism, or cubism? Basically, you need to pick a technology that sounds relevant, and start reading / watching / interacting with some tutorial resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code if that's what you intend to do

```
<a href="page1.html" target="myIframe">Page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" target="myIframe">Page 2</a>

<iframe name="myIframe" src="page1.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work as are as it goes.

Comment: edit* Thanks @Alexsander Gutierreez! seems to work! I've been trying to do this in a simple way for longer than I'm willing to admit and only finding methods that I felt were way too complicated for what I was trying to do.